# Can not install NuGet package

Tags: c#, nuget, unity-container, enterprise-library

I am trying to add the Unity package to my solution, but I keep receiving the listed message:

> *Attempting to resolve dependency 'Unity (≥ 3.5.1404.0)'.*
>
> *'Unity' already has a dependency defined for 'CommonServiceLocator'.*

Any Idea how to fix this?

Comment: Which version of nuget PM you are using, older version of nuget can be problem here.

Comment: 2.0.30625.9003 // VS2012

Comment: update nuget PM, 2.8.50313.46 is current version I think, Look for the latest for VS 2012

Comment: yep, solved it! Thanks!

Comment: Good, I am making this answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This problem arises with older version of nuget. Update nuget PM, 2.8.50313.46 is current version, Look for the latest for VS 2012

Comment: I've the latest Nuget "NuGet Package Manager 2.8.60318.667" but I get Install-Package : 'System.Collections' already has a dependency defined for 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms'. when trying to install Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Custom.AzureStorage -Pre

Comment: After updating NuGet, I uninstalled and re-installed the offending package and then it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You are using Higher version .Net framework.
And you are adding Lower version of Unity in to it.

your Application Framework will be above 4.0 or 4.0 and you are adding Unity frame work which is of .net  frame 3.5.