# How update NuGet Package Manager?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget

I have the same problem as in topic: [Can not install NuGet package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286522/can-not-install-nuget-package) . I suppose that I should update my NuGet Package Manager. I try to make it as described here: https://docs.nuget.org/docs/start-here/installing-nuget . But in updates I have not items. Thus my question is how can I update my NuGet Manager? I can not find good instructions. I am using Visual Studio 2012 (Express edition for Windows Desktop).

Comment: What version of the NuGet package manager is installed? Tools - Extensions and Updates - Installed tab.

Comment: Version: 2.0.30717.9005

Comment: Sorry, the version is 2.8.50313.31

Comment: That version looks pretty recent. So it should have fixed the problem linked to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286522/can-not-install-nuget-package - You could try uninstalling the NuGet package manager and then installing it again through the Extensions and Updates dialog. There may be a more recent version. In VS 2013 my version is 2.8.50313.46 - not sure about VS 2012