# 'Portable.BouncyCastle' already has a dependency defined for 'System.Collections'

Tags: c#, nuget, bouncycastle, bamboo, nuget-package-restore

This error occurs on the Bamboo build server during a command that restores my solution's NuGet packages.  I can bypass this error by disabling the package restore task; however, this is only a temporary fix.  Is there any way I can check if the dependency exists while running the task?  This error occurs before MSBUILD is running. I am using .NET 4.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `already has a dependency defined for` error when installing a NuGet package is due to a [bug in older versions of NuGet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286522/can-not-install-nuget-package).

You should look at updating NuGet on the build server or run your own build step that uses a version of NuGet that you download or deploy separately.

Answer (score 2):

This issue is fixed if you use nuget version: 3.4.4+

https://dist.nuget.org/index.html

I would recommend using latest version

Comment: This worked for me. When I went to Extensions > Tools in VS13, it was not giving me an option to update NuGet, which made me think I had the latest version. However, I didn't, and was able to upgrade from 2.8 --> 2.12 using your link.

Comment: I'm using Nuget 2.8.7 and I still have this issue, so your claim about being fixed in 2.8.6 is wrong

Comment: still I updating to latest nuget does fix the issue. right?