# Issue while installing the next-gen version of twilio-csharp

Tags: c#, twilio

While installing the next-gen version of twilio-csharp in Visual Studio 2013 (used Install-Package with the -Pre switch), but the below error happened.

```
PM> Install-Package Twilio -Pre
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Portable.JWT (= 1.0.5)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json (≥ 8.0.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Portable.BouncyCastle (≥ 1.8.0)'.
Install-Package : 'Portable.BouncyCastle' already has a dependency defined for 'System.Collections'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Twilio -Pre
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

I tried taking help from an existing [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314400/nuget-add-reference-error-while-installing-packages) but to no success. Though its an alpha version, it should work... am not sure if am doing something incorrectly.

Comment: That looks like an issue with the dependencies of the BouncyCastle library.  Report it to them... if it is alpha it may have been modified recently and come with a pleasant bug.

Comment: Instead of simply -pre, try the following command: `Install-Package Twilio -prerelease`

Comment: This question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36662092/738188

Comment: Thanks for taking time out and answering... i should have answered my question too. Megan's comment helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Megan for your comment... I downloaded the stable version and it worked fine. Also, later on I upgraded to the async version of the api's and that worked like a charm too.