# How do i install the Twilio package in Visual Studio using NuGet manager?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Please help me with the Twilio package installation in Visual Studio. I get the following error message when I try to install through NuGet manager.

> Attempting to resolve dependency 'JWT (≥ 1.3.4)'. 'Twilio' already has
>   a dependency defined for 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens'.

Comment: You may be running an older version of NuGet. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/36662092/215552.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all am ok now I updated the nuget manager to the latest version