# Automapper Nuget Package failed

Tags: c#, automapper

I tried to install http://automapper.org/ but this resulted in an error.

`Install-Package : 'AutoMapper' already has a dependency defined for 'Microsoft.CSharp'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package AutoMapper
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand`

Any ideas?

Comment: Here's http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23286522/can-not-install-nuget-package
Hope it helps.

Comment: I have asked my system administrator to update nuget, we will know tomorrow!

Comment: 2 days later, still no solution, but IT Server management is looking into it, will get a fix, but it might take some days. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your version of nuget package manager is current and if the version of the .net framework you are using is supported by the nuget package you are trying to install

Comment: I have asked my system admin,  we will know tomorrow! Thanks!

Comment: @JpHouten you can check it in the visual studio about window

Comment: I know,  i have a very old version,  6.0 or something

Comment: @Zbigniew i found out that i have version 2.7 and nuget themself are on 2.12.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue in VS2010 with NuGet package manager 2.8.60318.667 version. so, I have installed the older version of the Automapper 4.0.4 and its work for me.

try to install Install-Package Automapper -Version 4.0.4