# NuGet Package Manager: 'AutoMapper' already has a dependency defined for 'Microsoft.CSharp'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nuget, automapper

I'm trying to add AutoMapper as a dependency to a project using NuGet on Visual Studio Premium 2012, but it fails.

It says:

> Operation failed
>   'AutoMapper' already has a dependency defined for
>   'Microsoft.CSharp'.

I'm able to add other dependencies.

I'm using the last version of the package manager for VS 2012:

> NuGet Package Manager   2.8.60318.667

Any ideas what should I check?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automapper Nuget Package failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38186799/automapper-nuget-package-failed)

Comment: @Venky the difference between that question and mine is that I'm using the last version of nugget package manager

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Seems to be a problem with the current version of automapper:

> AutoMapper 5.0.0 Tuesday, June 28, 2016

I tried with the previous version and it works:

```
PM> Install-Package AutoMapper -Verbose
Install-Package : 'AutoMapper' already has a dependency defined for 'Microsoft.CSharp'.
At line:1 char:16
+ Install-Package <<<<  AutoMapper -Verbose
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

PM> Install-Package AutoMapper -Version 4.2.1
Installing 'AutoMapper 4.2.1'.
Successfully installed 'AutoMapper 4.2.1'.
```

So, if you can't update NuGet Package Manager, the answer is:

```
PM> Install-Package AutoMapper -Version 4.2.1
```

Comment: I had this issue and was getting this exact error from a VSTS Build task for NuGet Packager. I downgraded to 4.2.1 and that fixed the error.

Comment: Before I downgraded I tried to upgrade to 5.0.2 and it still gave me that error.

Comment: I get this    : Unable to find version '4.2.1' of package 'AutoMapper'.At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package AutoMapper -Version 4.2.1

Comment: The correct answer is the higher voted one by Matt Ward. This solution does work, but it's a very short-term fix...

Comment: @MPritchard Matt's solution doesn't work for VS2012, which was one of my problems

Comment: Unfortunately this is still an issue...
- Visual Studio 2017
- AutoMapper v6.2.2
- Microsoft.CSharp v4.4.1

Also the -- remove all, then add CSharp and then Automapper --
 solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 95):

The problem is that your NuGet Package Manager is too old. You need [NuGet 2.12](http://docs.nuget.org/release-notes/nuget-2.12) since this supports the newer .NETStandard frameworks that the AutoMapper 5.0.1 NuGet package is using.

The AutoMapper has a group dependency which specifies a target framework of .NETStandard. Since your version of NuGet Package Manager is too old it does not recognise this target framework and converts it to an Unknown target framework and you end up with duplicate frameworks since there .NETStandard is used a few times in that NuGet package. This causes the error:

```
'AutoMapper' already has a dependency defined for 'Microsoft.CSharp'
```

Unfortunately NuGet 2.12 is not available for Visual Studio 2012 but is available for Visual Studio 2013.

So either you need to update to Visual Studio 2013 or above, or you will have to use the older AutoMapper NuGet package which does not support .NETStandard.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I think you meant that "is not available" for VS 2012

Comment: For reasons beyond my power I'm stuck with VS 2012, so I will stay with the previos version

Answer (score 30):

I ended up needing to update NuGet.exe that was included in the solution to be able to build NuGet packages by running:

`nuget.exe update -self`

Comment: That fixed the problem for me.
It should be the right answer because actually downgrading AutoMapper is not a proper answer.

Comment: Except that this still happens today using Nuget 4.5.1. It appears to be an issue specific to AutoMapper

Answer (score 27):

I had the same issue on VS2013.  I had to update to VS2013 Update 5 and get the latest nuget distro for VS2013 at 
https://dist.nuget.org/visualstudio-2013-vsix/v2.12.0/NuGet.Tools.vsix

Once that was done, I rebooted Visual Studio. After that I was able to use the Automapper 5.0.2 package

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks for saving my day.

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks. (I needed restart VS after install the new version of Nuget)

Answer (score 17):

Go to Visual Studio > Tools > Extension and Updates

Find Updates in left accordion menu, Go to Visual Studio Gallery.

You will find a update for Nuget.

Update the nuget package and try installing or builing the project.

Thanks,
GT

Comment: Worked for me :)

Answer (score 2):

An other workaround if you're stuck with VS2012 and the old Nuget version:

- Find the Cache folder of VS 2012's Nuget Package Manager (with `Tools` - `Options` - `Nuget Package Manager`)
- Open `AutoMapper.5.x.x.nupkg` with your favorite Zip Tool
- Modify the file `AutoMapper.nuspec` - I simply deleted all dependencies except `.NETFramework4.5`
- Add the cache folder as a Nuget source (also in `Tools` - `Options` - `Nuget Package Manager`)
- Install Automapper either with the console or the GUI but make sure to choose first the newly added cache folder as package source.

Of course, the next version of Automapper probably needs to be adapted, too, in order to install it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a mismatch between the .NET version used by the Automapper package and your project.  Can you confirm the .NET version that your project is using?

Answer (score 0):

Automapper 6.0.2 - nuget 2.8.8 gives this error. Needed to update to 3.4.4 to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

Removed both CSharp and AutoMapper. Installed CSharp (4.0.0.0) first and then added Automapper (6.1.1.0). This resolved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I observed this exact problem when opening a project with Visual Studio 2010.

After opening with VS2017, I was able to install AutoMapper without any error.