# Even with Nuget.exe 4.1.0 - Serilog already has a dependency defined for 'Microsoft.CSharp'

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nuget, serilog

I know there's an answer for this question from 2016 but it's not working today. I have VS2013 with the latest CU installed.

My Nuget package source settings:[image]

I want to install the nu-get package "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer". First, I ensure nuget is up to date by navigating to the ".nuget" folder of the solution's folder and running "nuget update -self":

[image]

Unfortunately, I still get the error when trying to add the package:
[image]

If I try to update nuget from the "Extensions and Updates" page of VS then I get a 403 error as shown below:[image]

The 403 does suggest a proxy issue but other packages can be installed to the same dev box ok. I just installed "Apache log4net" from the Manage NuGet Packages window - no problem

Any ideas of a work-around for this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this I had to:

- logon to a PC not connected to the corporate proxy
- download the latest version of the nuget package manager (VSIX) for VS2013 from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuGetTeam.NuGetPackageManagerforVisualStudio2013
- copy the VSIX to my corporate dev VM and install

Answer (score 0):

This might be related to the fact that you now (with the new NuGet CLI tool version) need to use the new NuGet API.

from [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/)

> NuGet feed v3 (VS 2015 and later / NuGet v3.x and above): https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
>   NuGet feed v2 (VS 2013 and earlier / NuGet 2.x): https://www.nuget.org/api/v2

You can check (and edit) your NuGet Package Sources under Tools, Options, NuGet Package Manager, Package Sources.

@Rob Bowman, in response to your comment and looking at the screenshot of your *Available package sources*, try edit your default nuget.org to **https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json** or add a new source and make sure they're both enabled. Maybe that'll do the trick.

Update: maybe manually updating the NuGet Package Manager (since updating it through *Extensions and Updates* is not working) solves the problem. [NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio 2013](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuGetTeam.NuGetPackageManagerforVisualStudio2013).
Going to Visual Studio menu *Help, About* should display the currently installed version of this extension (and others).

Comment: Thanks Emiel but it seems this is set correctly - I've updated question with a screenshot

Comment: I'm afraid adding https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json as an additional source made no difference, when attempting to add "Serilog.Sinks.MSSqlServer" I still get "Serilog already has a dependency defined for Microsoft.CSharp

Comment: In this [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247961/nuget-package-manager-automapper-already-has-a-dependency-defined-for-micros#answer-38747408) someone mentions updating Visual Studio (to update 5) as the solution to a similar problem.

Comment: Could the 403 Forbidden (when trying to update the package manager) be proxy related? Maybe it is possible to manually install the extension, outside of Visual Studio from [the Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuGetTeam.NuGetPackageManagerforVisualStudio2013).

Comment: Good point - the 403 does suggest a proxy issue but other packages can be installed to the same dev box ok. I just installed "Apache log4net" from the Manage NuGet Packages window - no problem.