# 'AutoMapper' already has a dependency defined for 'Microsoft.CSharp'

Tags: nuget, automapper, nuget-package

When I am trying to install 'AutoMapper' it gives me an error "'AutoMapper' already has a dependency defined for 'Microsoft.CSharp'" in VS2010.I am trying to install Automapper latest version AutoMapper.6.1.0. I have already tried the following things but it's not worked for me.

1) Updated Nuget Package manager with latest version 2.8.60318.667
2) I have also manually deleted refernece from Automapper nuspec XML file

Please any one suggest me what can be issue for this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247961/nuget-package-manager-automapper-already-has-a-dependency-defined-for-micros

Answer (score 0):

After installing an older version of the Automapper its work for me. try to use Install-Package Automapper -Version 4.0.4 command from package manager console.