# 'Iesi.Collections' already has a dependency defined for 'NETStandard.Library

Tags: visual-studio-2013, nhibernate, nuget, fluent-nhibernate

I'm trying to install the FluentNHibernate using Nuget but whenever I try it throws an exception `'Iesi.Collections' already has a dependency defined for 'NETStandard.Library` and I don't know how could I fix it.

How could I fix this problem ?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading nuget? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247961/nuget-package-manager-automapper-already-has-a-dependency-defined-for-micros

Comment: @Jordan Thanks for your hint. Now it works !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and had it resolved by following these procedures:
1. Right-click the project in the Solution Explorer and select the option 'Manage NuGet Packages'.
2. At the LHS pane, click 'Online' from the list, then type any package name you want on the upper
    right search field. 
3. Select and Install. If there are dependencies, the system will add them automaically (the right versions of course).
4. Restart VS if necessary.
Note: the listed procedures require an internet connection.