# 'MySql.Data' already has a dependency defined for 'System.Text.Encoding.CodePages'

Tags: mono, nuget, monodevelop

I'm trying to add the Mysql.Data nuget package in Monodevelop, but I'm getting this error. Note I'm using Monodevelop on Linux.

The nuget manager log:

```
Adding MySql.Data...
Downloading MySql.Data 6.10.5...
'MySql.Data' already has a dependency defined for 'System.Text.Encoding.CodePages'.
```

Comment: This will be because the version of NuGet that is being used by MonoDevelop is older than NuGet 2.12 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38247961/nuget-package-manager-automapper-already-has-a-dependency-defined-for-micros - so you would need a later MonoDevelop.