# How to upgrade NuGet in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Ran into the following error during the Google Cloud Platform Bookshelf tutorial:

> Error 1   NuGet Package restore failed for project 2-structured-data: The 'Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms 1.0.1' package requires NuGet client version '2.12' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.8.50926.663'..

Where do I update NuGet?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Found it in the menu under Tools -> Extensions and Updates -> Updates tab -> Visual Studio Gallery.

Answer (score 4):

You can download the NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio 2013 from

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuGetTeam.NuGetPackageManagerforVisualStudio2013

and install it on your machine. The version of NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio 2013 which is available on this download URL is 2.12.0.817.

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Right click on References and choose 
Manage NuGet Packages.
Then search NuGet

Comment: Oddly enough, this method will only show the NuGet version currently installed. To update NuGet itself, you have to open the Updates tab (as explained in the accepted answer).