# SendGrid not working in c# application

Tags: c#, nuget, sendgrid

I have created application, which is in Visual Studio 2013 update 4 and .Net framework is 4.5. Now, want to implement SendGrid for sending mail. But its giving me error like below :

```
The 'System.Net.Http 4.0.0' package requires NuGet client version '3.0' or above, but the current NuGet version is '2.12.0.817'.
```

And when I am trying to upgrade the Nuget its not showing any update(see image). Not getting what to do

[image]

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013
Version 12.0.31101.00 Update 4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upgrade NuGet in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42045536/how-to-upgrade-nuget-in-visual-studio-2013)

Comment: Please update your question to show a screenshot of where you aren't seeing updates. Is there a particular reason you are using VS 2013? That is a **very old** version... Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/47731961/34092 help?

Answer (score 1):

NuGet 2.x clients are compatible with VS 2013
NuGet 3.x clients are compatible with VS 2015. 
NuGet 4.x clients are compatible with VS 2017.

tl;dr
There is no way to install that package while using VS 2013.

Refer to https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuGetTeam.NuGetPackageManagerforVisualStudio2013

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NuGetTeam.NuGetPackageManagerforVisualStudio2015

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-ui